# SAT for an LTL formula

Tags: optimization, logic, satisfiability

A SAT-solver proofs satisfiability of a propositional formula F. 
However, is it possible to use SAT for testing the satisfiability of a LTL formula?
For example, can we proof that the following LTL formula is unsatisfiable?

G (A => B) and (A = True) and (B = False)

It would be great if you could point to a SAT-solver that can handle this.

Thank you very much!

Comment: It looks like there are some procedures for working with linear temporal logic that work by turning formulas into Buchi automata and then reasoning about those automata. I'm not at all familiar with them, though.

Answer (score -1):

Because is possible to generate a buchi automata from an LTL formula if the automata is empty means that is not possible to satisfy the original formula.